# Ordered index vs clustered index

Tags: database, indexing, rdbms

What is the difference between "ordered index" and "clustered index"? Is clustered index some variation of ordered index?
I know that clustered index defines order in which the data are physically stored in the table. But what is "ordered index"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordered index, index values are ordered in index data structure, separate from main data. Each index value points to a position in data file, which might be ordered by another key or not ordered at all.

In clustered index, all records in data file are ordered by the key, not just index data structure.